# Some HTML input fields get cleared off on PHP validation, others don't

Tags: php, xhtml

Here is the problem.
I have data validation and sanitation code in PHP and an HTML form.
When there is some field left empty on the form, the validation code executes and prints a message. I thought I designed the form the way all the filled out fields retain their input data at that point. However, it proves to be inconsistent. For example, first and last name fields become empty, whereas the phone and street fields still have the data entered by a user before the validation occurred.

Here is the HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="firstname">FIRST NAME*:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname?>" />
</p>    

<p>
    <label for="lastname">LAST NAME*:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname?>" />
</p>    

<p>
    <label for="phone">TELEPHONE NUMBER*:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone?>" />
</p>

    <p>
    <label for="street">STREET ADDRESS*:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="street" id="street" value="<?php echo $street?>" />
</p>
```

Here is the validation script:

```
if ($_POST['firstname'] != "") {
        $_POST['firstname'] = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['firstname'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid first name.<br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your first name.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['lastname'] != "") {
        $_POST['lastname'] = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['lastname'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid last name.<br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your last name.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['phone'] != "") {
        $phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        if ($_POST['phone'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid phone number.<br/><br/>';  
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your phone number.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['street'] != "") {
        $street = filter_var($_POST['street'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['street'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid street address.<br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your street address.<br/>';
    }
```

To me all the fields look the same.
What could cause the inconsistency?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting up your `$phone` and `$street` variables, but not `$firstname` or `$lastname`. Instead you are are reassigning the `$_POST` variables:

`$_POST['lastname'] = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

[`filter_var`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) returns either the filtered input or `false` if the filter fails, so you should also be checking that the result of your filter is not `false`, (instead of `== ""`) in order to trigger your error.

For instance:

```
if ($_POST['firstname'] != "")
{
  $firstname = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  if ($firstname === false)
  {
    $errors .= 'Please enter a valid first name.<br/><br/>';
  }
}
else
{
  $errors .= 'Please enter your first name.<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so, so, so very much!
They ARE different after all, and I just didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

Compare:

```
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

With:

```
$_POST['firstname'] = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

With the phone number and the address you are storing it in a variable and then printing the contents of that variable. With the first and last name you are storing the sanitized value in the post array, and then printing some uninitialised variable.

The clean solution would be to change either where you store the phone number and address or where you store the first and last name, but that might need changes in code you haven't provided. Changing the following is sure to work:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname?>" />
```

becomes:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']?>" />
```

and:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname?>" />
```

becomes:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastname']?>" />
```